# How to use EF DbConext outside of Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm building ASP.Net app which is a simulator, lots of action will happens outside of Controller as separate threat, but I'm struggling to create DbContext connection outside of Controller. I know I could use `OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)` but it doesn't look to my as most elegant way to do it.

I through something like this should work:

```
public class SimRepository : ISimRepository
{
    public IConfiguration _configuration;
    public DbContextOptionsBuilder _dbOptions;

    public SimRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;

        _dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
        _dbOptions.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    }

    public void LatheIn()
    {
        using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext(_dbOptions.Options))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

but I receive this error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions' to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<Simulator_Line.Server.AppDbContext>
```

In Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddMvc();

    //Enable use of appsettings.json outside of Startup.cs
    services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
}
```

If my approach is incorrect, I'm open to for changes.

**EDIT**

```
    public class LatheController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly SimRepository _simRrepo;

    public LatheController(AppDbContext dbContext, SimRepository latheRepo)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _simRrepo = latheRepo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Lathe> GetLathes()
    {
        _simRrepo.LatheIn();



        return _dbContext.Lathes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already registered the DbContext in the service collection. Just inject it into the dependent class so that it can be resolved when the dependent class is being resolved

```
public class SimRepository : ISimRepository {
    public readonly AppDbContext db;

    public SimRepository(AppDbContext db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public void LatheIn() {
        //...use db
    }
}
```

### Update

You can create a factory

```
public interface IAppDbContextFactory {
    AppDbContext Create();
}
```

Which be used for creating instances as needed

```
public class SimRepository : ISimRepository {
    public readonly IAppDbContextFactory factory;

    public SimRepository(IAppDbContextFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void LatheIn() {
        using (AppDbContext db = factory.Create()) {
            //...use db
        }
    }
}
```

Factory implementation could look like

```
public class AppDbContextFactory : IAppDbContextFactory {
    private readonly IServiceProvider servideProvider;

    public AppDbContextFactory(IServiceProvider servideProvider) {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public AppDbContext Create() {
        return serviceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>();
    }
}
```

Make sure to register the your types with the service collection.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddMvc();

    //Enable use of appsettings.json outside of Startup.cs
    services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

    services.AddSingleton<IAppDbContextFactory, AppDbContextFactory>();
    services.AddTransient<ISimRepository, SimRepository>();
}
```

So that it can be used where needed

```
public class SomeController : Controller {
    private readonly ISimRepository simRepository;
    public SomeController(ISimRepository simRepository) {
        this.simRepository = simRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult SomeAction() {
        simRepository.LatheIn();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```